# Как правильно добавлять новую DOM Node?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Вырезал пример из моего проекта и сильно упростил:
Данный код создаст один нужный мне фрагмент. Дело в том, что я хочу создавать неограниченное количество фрагментов и каждый раз создавать НОВУЮ колонку и работать с ней. Эдакой канбан. Ошибка в том что будет копироваться абсолютно всё: значения `input`, `textarea` и так далее. Как правильно реализовать решение? Гуглил Shadow DOM, и пробовал использовать но в итоге не понятно какой подход правильный. з.ы. Делаю нативно, без React.

```js
const deskWrapper = document.querySelector('.deskWrapper');
const addButton = document.querySelector('.js-add-card');



const addNewDesk = () => {
  const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
  const taskDeskItem = document.querySelector('.taskDesk');
  const newDesk = taskDeskItem.cloneNode(true);
  
  fragment.appendChild(newDesk);
  deskWrapper.appendChild(fragment);
  addListeners()
  
};

const addListeners = () => {
   const newLastDesk = deskWrapper.children[deskWrapper.children.length - 1]; // ищем новую доску через родителя
   newLastDesk.addEventListener('click', addNewDesk);
}
 
 
 

 addButton.addEventListener('click', addNewDesk)
```

```css
.deskWrapper {
  background: url("../img/deskWrapper/background.jpg") no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 21px 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start; }

.taskDesk {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  min-height: 43px;
  max-height: 614px;
  background: #DFE3E6;
  border-radius: 3px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  margin-right: 12px; }

.taskDesk_box {
  padding: 8px 12px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: nowrap; }

.taskDesk_title {
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 19px;
  margin-bottom: 12px; }
  .taskDesk_title .inactive {
    display: none; }

.task_list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto; }

.task_item {
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px rgba(9, 45, 66, 0.25);
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 19px;
  font-family: "Montserrat", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  word-wrap: break-word; }

.taskDesk_add_box {
  width: 100%;
  background: #DFE3E6;
  border-radius: 3px;
  position: relative; }
  .taskDesk_add_box.active .taskDesk_area {
    display: block;
    height: auto; }
  .taskDesk_add_box.active .taskDesk_button_save {
    display: flex; }
  .taskDesk_add_box.active .taskDesk_button_close {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 10; }
  .taskDesk_add_box.active .add_task {
    display: none; }
  .taskDesk_add_box.emptyArea .taskDesk_button_save {
    background-color: #bbb;
    pointer-events: none; }
  .taskDesk_add_box.addColumn .add_title {
    display: block; }
  .taskDesk_add_box.addColumn .add_task {
    display: none; }
  .taskDesk_add_box.addColumn .taskDesk_input.active {
    display: block; }
  .taskDesk_add_box.addColumn .taskDesk_save_title.active {
    display: flex; }
  .taskDesk_add_box .taskDesk_save_title.emptyInput {
    background: #39C071;
    pointer-events: auto; }

.taskDesk_button_add {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  color: #6B808C;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 19px;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  cursor: pointer; }
  .taskDesk_button_add:hover, .taskDesk_button_add:active, .taskDesk_button_add:focus {
    color: #000; }
  .taskDesk_button_add:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background: url("../img/taskDesk/add.svg") no-repeat center;
    background-size: contain;
    margin-right: 8px; }

.taskDesk_area {
  display: none;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 19px;
  resize: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px rgba(9, 45, 66, 0.25);
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-family: "Montserrat", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  transition: all .3s ease; }

.taskDesk_input {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 4px 12px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px rgba(9, 45, 66, 0.25);
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-family: "Montserrat", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  border: none;
  margin-bottom: 8px; }

.taskDesk_button_save {
  display: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 152px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #39C071;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 19px;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all .2s ease; }
  .taskDesk_button_save:hover, .taskDesk_button_save:active, .taskDesk_button_save:focus {
    background: #45c04f; }

.taskDesk_button_close {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 9px;
  right: 0;
  background: url("../img/taskDesk/cross.svg") no-repeat center;
  background-size: contain;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -10;
  transition: all 0s; }

.add_title {
  display: none;
  margin-bottom: 8px; }

.taskDesk_save_title {
  display: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 152px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 19px;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  pointer-events: none;
  background: #bbb; }
```

```html
<section class="deskWrapper">
  <div class="taskDesk">
    <div class="taskDesk_box">
      <h3 class="taskDesk_title"></h3>
      <ul class="task_list">
      
      </ul>
      <form class="taskDesk_add_box emptyArea">
        <button class="taskDesk_button_add add_task js-add-card" type="button">Добавить еще одну карточку</button>
        <input name="name"/>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Еще можно воспользоваться тэгом template https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template

Comment: @Дмытрык  Уже заюзал, работает) только вот обнаружилось что IE выдает ошибку `Не удалось получить свойство "cloneNode" ссылки, значение которой не определено или является NULL`. Почему так?

Answer (score 0):

Так с самого начала скопируйте состояние доски и потом чистенькую вставляйте.

```js
const deskWrapper = document.querySelector('.deskWrapper');
const addButton = document.querySelector('.js-add-card');
const newDesk = (function(){
    const taskDeskItem = document.querySelector('.taskDesk').cloneNode(true);
    return function(){
        return taskDeskItem.cloneNode(true);
        }
    })();


const addNewDesk = () => {
  const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

  fragment.appendChild(newDesk());
  deskWrapper.appendChild(fragment);
  addListeners()
  
};

const addListeners = () => {
   const newLastDesk = deskWrapper.children[deskWrapper.children.length - 1].getElementsByTagName('button')[0]; // ищем новую доску через родителя
   newLastDesk.addEventListener('click', addNewDesk);
}
 
 
 

 addButton.addEventListener('click', addNewDesk)
```

```css
.deskWrapper {
  background: url("../img/deskWrapper/background.jpg") no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 21px 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start; }

.taskDesk {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  min-height: 43px;
  max-height: 614px;
  background: #DFE3E6;
  border-radius: 3px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  margin-right: 12px; }

.taskDesk_box {
  padding: 8px 12px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: nowrap; }

.taskDesk_title {
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 19px;
  margin-bottom: 12px; }
  .taskDesk_title .inactive {
    display: none; }

.task_list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto; }

.task_item {
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px rgba(9, 45, 66, 0.25);
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 19px;
  font-family: "Montserrat", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  word-wrap: break-word; }

.taskDesk_add_box {
  width: 100%;
  background: #DFE3E6;
  border-radius: 3px;
  position: relative; }
  .taskDesk_add_box.active .taskDesk_area {
    display: block;
    height: auto; }
  .taskDesk_add_box.active .taskDesk_button_save {
    display: flex; }
  .taskDesk_add_box.active .taskDesk_button_close {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 10; }
  .taskDesk_add_box.active .add_task {
    display: none; }
  .taskDesk_add_box.emptyArea .taskDesk_button_save {
    background-color: #bbb;
    pointer-events: none; }
  .taskDesk_add_box.addColumn .add_title {
    display: block; }
  .taskDesk_add_box.addColumn .add_task {
    display: none; }
  .taskDesk_add_box.addColumn .taskDesk_input.active {
    display: block; }
  .taskDesk_add_box.addColumn .taskDesk_save_title.active {
    display: flex; }
  .taskDesk_add_box .taskDesk_save_title.emptyInput {
    background: #39C071;
    pointer-events: auto; }

.taskDesk_button_add {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  color: #6B808C;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 19px;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  cursor: pointer; }
  .taskDesk_button_add:hover, .taskDesk_button_add:active, .taskDesk_button_add:focus {
    color: #000; }
  .taskDesk_button_add:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background: url("../img/taskDesk/add.svg") no-repeat center;
    background-size: contain;
    margin-right: 8px; }

.taskDesk_area {
  display: none;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 19px;
  resize: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px rgba(9, 45, 66, 0.25);
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-family: "Montserrat", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  transition: all .3s ease; }

.taskDesk_input {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 4px 12px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px rgba(9, 45, 66, 0.25);
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-family: "Montserrat", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  border: none;
  margin-bottom: 8px; }

.taskDesk_button_save {
  display: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 152px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #39C071;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 19px;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all .2s ease; }
  .taskDesk_button_save:hover, .taskDesk_button_save:active, .taskDesk_button_save:focus {
    background: #45c04f; }

.taskDesk_button_close {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 9px;
  right: 0;
  background: url("../img/taskDesk/cross.svg") no-repeat center;
  background-size: contain;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -10;
  transition: all 0s; }

.add_title {
  display: none;
  margin-bottom: 8px; }

.taskDesk_save_title {
  display: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 152px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 19px;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  pointer-events: none;
  background: #bbb; }
```

```html
<section class="deskWrapper">
  <div class="taskDesk">
    <div class="taskDesk_box">
      <h3 class="taskDesk_title"></h3>
      <ul class="task_list">
      
      </ul>
      <form class="taskDesk_add_box emptyArea">
        <button class="taskDesk_button_add add_task js-add-card" type="button">Добавить еще одну карточку</button>
        <input name="name"/>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```